# Move horizontalscrollView of Android from left to right

Tags: android, android-widget, android-animation, android-scrollview

I'm using **horizontalscrollView** along with the animation to move set of images as a slideshow. I'm able to move the images from right to left using the following code :

```
 public void getScrollMaxAmount(){
    int actualWidth = (horizontalOuterLayout.getMeasuredWidth()-512);
    scrollMax   = actualWidth;
}

public void startAutoScrolling(){
    if (scrollTimer == null) {
        scrollTimer =   new Timer();
        final Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                moveScrollView();
            }
        };

        if(scrollerSchedule != null){
            scrollerSchedule.cancel();
            scrollerSchedule = null;
        }
        scrollerSchedule = new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
            }
        };

        scrollTimer.schedule(scrollerSchedule, 30, 30);
    }
}

public void moveScrollView(){
    scrollPos   =   (int) (horizontalScrollview.getScrollX() + 1.0);
    if(scrollPos >= scrollMax){
        scrollPos = 0;
    }
    horizontalScrollview.scrollTo(scrollPos, 0);

}
```

I now want to move the images from right to left as a slideshow. I'm unable to find the right formula/logic. Kindly assist me. :(

Comment: Do you want to move the images from left to right?

Comment: what is the issue you facing now ?

Comment: Yes I want to move the images from left to right in the slideshow. With the above code, I'm able to move the images from right to left ( along with the animation logic). Now I want to implement left to right.

Comment: Can someone help me with the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before starting the timer, set:

```
scrollPos= scrollMax;
```

Then use this moveScrollView function:

```
public void moveScrollView(){
    scrollPos   =   (int) (horizontalScrollview.getScrollX() - 1.0);
    if(scrollPos <= 0){
        scrollPos = scrollMax;
    }
    horizontalScrollview.scrollTo(scrollPos, 0);
}
```

For calculating the width of horizontalScrollview content:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        ...

    horizontalScrollview= (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.hsv);
    ViewTreeObserver vto = horizontalScrollview.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            horizontalScrollview.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            scrollMax= horizontalScrollview.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredWidth()-getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

        }
    });     
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I'm able to move the images from left to right. But the initial offset is still somehow set to 0 i guess. the images move to the left (till X axis 0 ) and from there they start moving towards right. :(

Comment: Your welcome. I think your calculation for scrollMax is wrong. I edited my solution and added scrollMax calculation.

Comment: I changed the formula. I have around 6 images. but the width is more than the width occupied by the images. So it is giving me blank space for a while and then the slideshow starts. :(

Comment: I tested my formula and it worked correctly. Put a LinearLayout in your HorScrollView and place your images in it.

Comment: Its working. Thanks so much for the inputs. One more doubt. Will I be able to configure the number of images to be displayed at a time during the scroll?

Comment: The requirement is to allow user to display the No. of Slides at a time. So if I select 2, I should be able to display 2 slides for the entire view, it scrolls and displays the next 2 and so on.

Comment: OK. For this purpose, i recommend you to change your method. An example : http://www.techipost.com/2011/06/15/android-image-slider-with-auto-slide-code/